# How do I convert this special case XML into CSV?

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I have been trying to convert the following XML

```
<root>
<data>
  <MEMBNO>11400116</MEMBNO> 
  <BASIC>15400.00</BASIC> 
  <BASIC>15000.00</BASIC> 
  <BASIC>14242.50</BASIC> 
</data>
<data>
   <MEMBNO>200</MEMBNO>
   <DOB>17/02/1975</DOB>
</data>
<data>
   <MEMBNO>16</MEMBNO>
   <BASIC>26354.00</BASIC>
</data>
</root>
```

into CSV like this.

```
MEMBNO,BASIC,DOB,
11400116,"15400.00\v15000.00\v,14242.00",,
200,,17/12/1975,
16,26354.00,,
```

**\v** is a vertical tab and it is supposed to print a newline when the word mail merge happening.

Could you pleas help me out solving this?

Thank you.

**I Haven't progressed anywhere. As of now I have no code with me.**

Comment: We only dealt with the XML before, we have used dataset.ReadXML() and we are supposed to get only one datatable but with this XML we are getting multiple datatable which breaks mail merge process. So I thought of converting to CSV, Shame on me, I haven't progressed anywhere.Sorry that I have no code with me right now.

Comment: I was trying to merge the multiple datatables into one, and I ran into problem when <data> repeated itself. I thought of changing this to CSV, I have very little experience in handling XML, So I needed a heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that only `<BASIC>` tag that can occur multiple times in one `<DATA>` tag, you can try as follow (see comments for what happen in detail, it is using [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and LINQ-to-XML) :

```
var xml = @"<root>
<data>
  <MEMBNO>11400116</MEMBNO> 
  <BASIC>15400.00</BASIC> 
  <BASIC>15000.00</BASIC> 
  <BASIC>14242.50</BASIC> 
</data>
<data>
   <MEMBNO>200</MEMBNO>
   <DOB>17/02/1975</DOB>
</data>
<data>
   <MEMBNO>16</MEMBNO>
   <BASIC>26354.00</BASIC>
</data>
</root>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var output = "";
//loop through each <data>
foreach(var data in doc.Descendants("data"))
{
    //get <MEMBNO> under current <data>
    var membno = (string)data.Element("MEMBNO");
    //get all <BASIC> under current <data>
    var basic = string.Join("\v", data.Elements("BASIC").Select(o => (string)o).ToArray());
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(basic)) basic = "\"" + basic + "\"";
    //get <DOB> under current <data>
    var dob = (string)data.Element("DOB");
    //construct line with format MEMBNO,BASIC,DOB,
    var line = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},", membno, basic, dob);

    output += line + Environment.NewLine;
}
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Codes above can be adjusted to accommodate unknown number of element and unknown element names under each `<data>`. Check updated code below, that will produce the same output as .csv sample in question without hardcoding element names (assume that `doc` variable is the same as in above code block) :

```
//get distinct list of element name under <data>
var columns = doc.Root.Elements("data").Elements().Select(o => o.Name.LocalName).Distinct().ToList();
var output = "";
//add header to 'output' : MEMBNO,BASIC,DOB,
columns.ForEach(o => output += o + ",");
foreach (var data in doc.Descendants("data"))
{
    var line = Environment.NewLine;
    foreach (var column in columns)
    {
        var cellValue = string.Join("\v", data.Elements(column).Select(o => (string)o).ToArray());
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellValue)) cellValue = "\"" + cellValue + "\"";
        line += cellValue + ",";
    }
    output += line;
}
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: Thanks @har07, Sorry I missed to mention that we don't know what elements will be there in XML file. The XML I mentioned is a sample, the elements could be anything, so I could hard code tag name.

Comment: from sample xml above, how can i know the order should be MEMBNO,BASIC,DOB, not MEMBNO,DOB,BASIC, or order doesn't matter?

Comment: I meant the column order in csv file outputted after processing the xml, should it be in particular order or not?

Comment: No It doesn't have to be, mail merge will map to the particular column by the name. Thanks for your helping.

Comment: check my update, you'll be able to adjust the code further if the requirement is slightly different from what it demonstrates currently. I assumed that each element under `<data>` can appear multiple times and should be treated the same way as `<BASIC>` element in your example.